# How can I use my Sinatra helpers in included modules?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have my routes and helpers defined in external files and included by Sinatra, however I'm new to Ruby and I can't now figure out how I can use my helper methods in my routes. When I run the code in RubyMine and access a profile URL I get the error "NoMethodError - undefined method `protected!'"

```
## Main class
require 'sinatra/base'
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
    register Sinatra::MyHelpers
    register ProfileRoutes
    ...
end


## Helpers include
require 'sinatra/base'
module Sinatra
  module LocutusHelpers
    def self.registered( app )

      app.before do
        ...
      end

      def protected!
        ...
      end

    end
  end
end


## Routes include
require 'sinatra/base'
module ProfileRoutes
  def self.registered( app )

    app.get '/profile/:userid' do
      protected!
      ...
    end

  end
end
```

I've tried  `def self.protected!` for the helper but then it cant access the request object.
I've also tried `Sinatra::MyHelpers.protected!`, `Sinatra.protected!` and `app.protected!`, errors are thrown for all of these too

Do you know how I can access the helpers from my routes? Or have I set something up incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing up [adding helpers from extensions](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html#extending-the-request-context-with-sinatrahelpers) and configuring your app from extensions.

You need to move `protected!` into a module, then when registering your extension add that module as a helpers module.

```
module LocutusHelpers
  # new module, move protected! into here
  module HelperMethods
    def protected!
      ...
    end
  end

  def self.registered( app )

    # add new hlpers module
    app.helpers HelperMethods

    # other extension setup as before...
    app.before do
      ...
    end

  end
end
```